# unregister_netdevice: waiting for eth1 to become free？

Tags: linux, networking

I used vconfig to create two vlan，phy0.1 and phy0.2
and change their name,

```
ip link set dev phy0.1 name eth0  (for Router lan)
ip link set dev phy0.2 name eth1. (for Router wan).
```

Now, for some purpose, I have to rem `phy0.1`.
However, when I rem `eth1` by below command,

```
ifconfig eth1 down
vconfig rem eth1.
```

It cannot work well, and get below message,

```
unregister_netdevice: waiting for eth1 to become free. Usage count = 1
```

Now how can I find out the process that is using eth1.
Or, if there is any other way to rem `eth1`?

Answer (score 7):

That looks like what is described in "[**When the blue whale sinks**](https://medium.com/@bcdonadio/when-the-blue-whale-sinks-55c40807c2fc)" by **[Bernardo Donadio](https://twitter.com/bcdonadio)**, and reported [initially in 2014 in a docker context](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/5618)

> This issue isn’t present in the Docker code itself, but rather in the Linux kernel code instead.
>   It affects not only Docker, but any kind of software that uses the Linux network stack to create devices and namespaces frequently like LXC, OpenStack, Rkt, Proxmox, etc…
>
> If you’ve already had some experience with multi-thread programming, you can instantly diagnose this as a race condition
>
> Once the bug is triggered, the situation now is the following: you’re unable to create, delete or change any network device in the whole system.
>   There’s absolutely no fix to the bug so far, except a few mitigations and the Windows-style workaround: reboot your computer. Seriously.
>
> Worse even is the fact that reproducing this issue is far from straightforward.
>   The Red Hat kernel (including CentOS) seems to be specially more prone to suffer from this problem, but all other distributions have reports of also being affected.
>
> As of the time of this publication (July 2017), a fix has already been released ([kernel 4.8](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/751eb6b6042a596b0080967c1a529a9fe98dac1d)) to the issue being encountered by hitting the bug in the IPv6 stack, but people are still get the annoying message and frozen behaviour, suggesting that the bug has multiple causes, spread all over the network subsystem of the kernel.

Comment: does it still without solution?

Answer (score 1):

This issue my probably occur in below occasion:
    you use `dev_hold` to increase refercount of device, but forget use `dev_put` to decrease it.
   `dev_hold` and `dev_put` are always used to match.
   `dev_get_by_name` wrap `dev_hold`. So you should use `dev_put` follow `dev_get_by_name`.

Comment: I have a similar issue. If your answer is correct (it indeed might be) the problem is probably in Kernel itself since all these functions are in Kernel. How can we check if and where a fix was released in Linux ?